# Как распаковать tar.bz2 архив (read only) в Ubuntu?

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu

Хочу `phpMyAdmin` установить. Cкачал архив, стандартным архиватором не желает распаковываться в нужную папку. Как это сделать через терминал?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
man tar tar -xjvf phpmyadmin.tar.bz2 .
```

Answer (score 1):

Проще в терминале выполнить `sudo aptitude install phpmyadmin`

Comment: Оно конечно проще, но безопасность под вопросом.

Comment: deb http://security... не отключаем из сорсес.лист, вопросов буде меньше. Тем более, что обновлять будет проще.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный, в данном случае bzip2 и похоже он не установлен.

> http://blog.mysoarer.ru/?p=90